# Why using docker compose gives other effect with ElasticSearch 8.1.2?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am following the tutorial from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html to run Elasticsearch and Kibana using Docker (or better `docker-compose`). I just need one node for testing purposes.

When I use:

```
docker network create elastic
docker run --name es01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.1.2
```

Everything works well, I get the expected information with certificate fingerprint and Kibana enrollment token (screen below).

But when I try to do (I think) the same using `docker-compose` I end up not getting the information from the image below. My `stack.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.1.2
        container_name: es01
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
```

and then I run it with `docker-compose -f stack.yml up`. Which runs the conatiner. Elasticsearch is running, but it never shows the certificate fingerprint nor the enrollment token.

Why would those two cases behave differently?

(My final goal is just to have Elasticsearch - can be single node - and Kibana in one `stack.yml` configured and running together.)

[image]

Comment: It is still the case.... extremely odd. even with tty  = true (-t parameter) it is not working as it should...

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/85047

Generating a new Password

```
docker exec -ti es01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

Generating a new enrollment token

```
docker exec -ti es01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
```